# How to use reflection to run two variables

Tags: java, reflection

I want to run this code

```
New main1().main2();
```

But replace main1 With a variable and replace main2 with a variable thank you

Comment: You're very persistent. I think this is the third time I've seen this question posted. Considering your previous posts are deleted, don't you think you should change your approach? How about taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before you post this question next time?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: I have taken a different approach look how long the first one is and now I have narrowed it down to three lines I think I have improved it a lot and my first post was closed not the other two. I don’t know what code to use so I have no code for it

Comment: Well, here's some bed time reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html

Comment: I checked this out and I don’t understand I am only 14 years old and the wording is quite complicated that is why I asked this code would be very useful for my game.

Comment: Trust me, you don't want to make your game overly complex by introducing reflection. Especially if you don't even understand the documentation. You should be asking the original question, which you tried to solve like this. Then we can give you proper advice. You don't need reflection.

Comment: I understand the way you think, but while this may seem like a clever solution, it's not something that works well especially in languages like Java. So why do you think you need to do the code in question dynamically?

Comment: It will just be used once to finish off my universal JFrame which will be a lot less complicated and save lots of time if I want to change design or layout as currently I have to change over 40 JFrames to this new universal and the more I add to the game the more JFrames I have so it would so much longer to change a design while if I finish this universal JFrame I could change a whole layout by changing one JFrame which seems a lot less complicated. So sorry for wasting your time but please could you tell me what code I would need for this Thank you.

Comment: I recommend going through the reflection questions on StackOverflow. I'm sure there'll be plenty of code snippets to go through, and the questions/answers/comments might be easier to read than the official tutorial. Your root problem is I guess bad design. That's an unfortunate part of the learning process in programming.

Comment: Yeah I admit I have a very bad design I will look through some reflection questions to understand it better

Comment: If `main1` is a variable, then `main1()` does not make any sense. Writing `main1()` implies that `main1` is a method, not a variable.

Comment: You do not new up a variable, you new up a class.  So I am having a very hard time understanding what you are even asking.  I would suggest giving some context.  IF you are newing up a variable, this flat out won't work.  If you have a class that is returned from a variable and you want to new that up, maybe try something like Class.forName(main1.main2()).newInstance().  But if main1 and main2 are both variables, you cannot do what you have written.  There is just a ton of inference one has to make to understand your question.

Comment: @FredK I don’t know how to do it with variables I was just using an example off what I want it to do I have tried to replace it with variable’s and it didn’t work that is why I was asking how to do it.

Comment: @Chewy the variable will be equal to a class the variable with have the class saved as string so main1 is the name of the file main class and is saved as string and the variable main2 is the public void name in the file and is saved as string as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked out a different way off doing it. To do it you make a new file let’s say it called ButtonDefinition and the code you would do to run it is

```
 new ButtonDefinition().ButtonDefinition1();
```

Then you would add in ButtonDefinition file

```
if (main1.equals(“Test”)){
    if (main2.equals(“Test2”)){
        New Test().Test2();
    }
}
```

So for each file you want to add you add this code to the ButtonDefinition file.